# Localization in elements in a form.

Tags: orbeon

I am trying to change the label in a element of a form in orbeon.

If I have a form in english, in the properties-local.xml I can define:

```
 <property as="xs:string"
 name="oxf.fr.resource.myapplication.myform.en.components.grid.insert-below" 
 value="New text to be shown"/>
```

In this case, I would change the label in a repeatable grid. Now "Insert below" would be changed to "New text to be shown". This works fine in my tests.

Now, if I change the form to dutch:

```
 <resource xml:lang="nl">
```

The buttons of the form runner and other elements is translated to dutch (great!). For example, the repeatable grid now has the label "Onder invoegen" .

But if I change the property as:

```
 <property as="xs:string"
 name="oxf.fr.resource.myapplication.myform.nl.components.grid.insert-below" 
 value="New text to be shown"/>
```

I expect that the repeatable grid label is changed, but still "Onder invoegen" is shown.

Is the property defined incorrectly? Do I need to add any extra property?

Comment: Trying to add extra parameter as `<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.available-languages.*.*" value="en nl"/>` doesn't help!

Comment: Just checking: have you tried restarting Tomcat after setting this property? (Unlike almost every other property, changes to the resources are cached aggressively for performance reasons, and are not taken into account "immediately".)

Comment: Yes, I have restarted tomcat. That means my proposal must work?

Comment: Yes, it not only should work, but also does work for me :). I set the 2 properties you have in your message, created a form with a repeated grid, in Form Builder, adding Dutch, and at runtime see the proper resources as overriden with the properties: http://i.imgur.com/ayKnDrP.gif. Did I maybe misunderstand the situation you're describing?

Comment: Let me check in a new form from the scratch. We will see if the issue is elsewere.

Comment: Got it, you'll let me know. Also, I'm not aware of any issue that was fixed recently with this, but if it isn't working for you with an empty form and you're not using the latest release (4.10, as I write this), you might want to try upgrading.

Comment: Ok, finally I can test it in a new installation of Orbeon (4.10). In this case seems that it is working correctly. Also with the same form everything is correct. I need to check the configuration in my old orbeon server to see what is wrong.

Comment: And the `oxf.fr.available-languages.*.*` property is not needed.

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad this is resolved, and thank you for the update.